# Why creating new column on a Pandas dataframe with not sorted index is slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to perform some basic calculation with the first occurring row and assign it to a new column in dataframe.

For simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100) for k in list('ABCDEFG')})

# drop duplicates 
first = df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first').copy()
%timeit first['H'] = first['A']*first['B'] + first['C'] - first['D'].max()
```

this gives

```
532 µs ± 5.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

if I reset the index it becomes almost x2 faster (just in case the difference is due to some caching, I rerun with different order multiple times, it gave same result)

```
# drop duplicates but reset index
first = df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first').reset_index(drop=True).copy()
%timeit  first['H'] = first['A']*first['B'] + first['C']

342 µs ± 7.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Although it's not that bag difference, I wonder what causes this. Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

I redid this simple test, the issue was not index related, it seems like have something to do with the copy of a dataframe:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100) for k in list('ABCDEFG')})

In [4]: # drop duplicates
   ...: first = df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first').copy()
   ...: %timeit first['H'] = first['A']*first['B'] + first['C'] - first['D'].max()
558 µs ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: # drop duplicates
   ...: first = df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first')
   ...: %timeit first['H'] = first['A']*first['B'] + first['C'] - first['D'].max()
/Users/sam/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  #!/Users/sam_dessa/anaconda3/bin/python
20.7 ms ± 826 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

making a copy and assign a new column took ~ **532 µs**  but directly operate on the dataframe itself (which pandas also gave warning) gave **20.7 ms**, same original question, what is causing this? Is it simply because the time spent on throwing out the warning?

Comment: why your second `%timeit` don't have `- first['D'].max()`?

Comment: ahhh... my apologies, i made the silly mistake, it was a typo, after adding that back it turns out to be the same performance. I'm not sure why though, I was expecting them to be different, because I'm using this to simulate a real data setting where I found reset_index gives faster speed. Let me see if I can replicate that.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for spotting the mistake, please see the updates.

Comment: I can not answer your question, but I discovered this [explanation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) on the pandas API. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986) looks promising too. I hope I have helped you by finding a north in your question.